# Sending value from JavaScript to PHP via ajax OnUpDtae

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to send a value 'idSelected' from javascript to update a php variable  using onUpdate (when the user clicks a button).
The javascript gets it values from a MagicToolBox.com Image tool and when we set an alert the value is shown correctly from within the javascript so that bit works fine.

I just can not seem to be able to get the php variable value to change onUpdate so when we use an action (button Press) it has the value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mzOptions = {};
mzOptions = {
    onUpdate: function() { 
     jQuery('.MagicZoom').next().html(jQuery(arguments[2]).attr('title')) ;

     $idSelected = jQuery(arguments[2]).attr('data-product-id') ; 

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://malonef.truska.co.uk/product/18",  
            type: "post", 
            data: { idSelected: $idSelected } ;
            });
        }
    } ;
</script>
```

and the php

```
<a  id="moodboxclick" data-id="<?php echo $_POST['idSelected'] ; ?>">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_moodboard">Add Colour to Moodboard</button>
</a>
```

In addition how do I set the value of for url to be the current page - can we use php

```
 $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

or does it need passed in show how. It is only the ## on the end that changes (18 in this case)

Comment: It helps if you write real HTML: http://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: php runs on the server, before the page is rendered, javascript on the client, via their, browser, after the page has rendered (by which point php has exited. Do some research on the lifecycle of a weppage

Comment: Code from initial post updated as I made a blunder with it.. sorry....

Comment: Yes Steve - I am a novice with ajax but am aware of this issue and that is what I am trying to overcome with the ajax. To update the php variable somehow based on the value in the JavaScript.
Can this be done? or am I wasting my time.